# How to send multi line string in json in GitHub actions?

Tags: string, github-actions

I am working on GitHub actions, and I have a case where I need to send a multiline string as json. I am getting some unexpected token error.

This is my test.md and
workflow:

```
---------------------------
  **test**
  - update something
  - another (update)
  
  **test2**
  - Add `test` to param
```

```
steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Get Log
      id: getLog
      run: |
        CHANGELOG="$(cat test.md)"
        CHANGELOG="$($CHANGELOG//'%'/'%25')"
        CHANGELOG="$($CHANGELOG//$'\n'/'%0A')" 
        CHANGELOG="$($CHANGELOG//$'\r'/'%0D')"
        echo "::set-output name=changeLog::$CHANGELOG"
    - name: Invoke CLI workflow with changelog
      uses: benc-uk/workflow-dispatch@v1
      with:
        workflow: Workflow publish
        token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
        repo: repo/name
        inputs: '{ "changeLog": "${{steps.getLog.outputs.changeLog}}"}'
```

I am getting an unexpected token error. How solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what an error are you getting ?

Comment: ```Error: Unexpected token 
 in JSON at position 43```

Comment: And when I am ```echo ${{steps.getLog.outputs.changeLog}}```,  json is printing in multiline without escape charecters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**There seem to be 2 issues you have in provided example.**

1. your string substitution seems invalid. that should be something like this.

```yaml
run: |
  CHANGELOG=$(cat test.md)
  CHANGELOG="${CHANGELOG//'%'/'%25'}"
  CHANGELOG="${CHANGELOG//$'\n'/'%0A'}"
  CHANGELOG="${CHANGELOG//$'\r'/'%0D'}"
  echo "::set-output name=changeLog::$CHANGELOG"
```

2. You are just composing invalid `json` for object.

```
inputs: '{ "changeLog": "${{steps.getLog.outputs.changeLog}}"}'
```

which outputs invalid json:

```json
{ "changeLog": "---------------------------
  **test**
  - update something
  - another (update)
  
  **test2**
  - Add `test` to param"}
```

**to fix this use [Context function `toJSON()`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#tojson)**

```yaml
inputs: '{ "changeLog": ${{ toJSON(steps.getLog.outputs.changeLog) }}}'
```

which outputs valid json:

```json
{ "changeLog": "---------------------------\n  **test**\n  - update something\n  - another (update)\n  \n  **test2**\n  - Add `test` to param"}
```

**EDIT**

I released small composite [Set text output action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/set-text-output) to handle multi-line strings.

```yaml
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: test changelog
  uses: mkungla/actions-set-text-output@v1
  id: get-changekog
  with:
    text: $(cat tests/test-changelog.md)
- run: echo "${{ steps.get-changekog.outputs.value }}"
```

Comment: @Andry feel free to raise issue with example what fails on https://github.com/mkungla/actions-set-text-output/issues This string substitution here works with most standard well formated markdown files, but does not handle any edge cases and other escape sequences.