# Is it possible to give multiline inputs in github actions workflow_dispatch?

Tags: github, workflow, github-actions

I have a workflow and I need to give multiline input to workflow. Something like below:

```
name: Test
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      change-log:
        description: 'Changelog'
        required: true
```

Here my changelog is multiline and when I am using the input it's not coming properly. Is there any way to pass multiline input correctly to a GitHub action?

Comment: I've seen a [similar question](https://github.community/t/multiline-inputs-for-workflow-dispatch/163906) on the Github Community without any answer from the support team yet. It may not be possible at the moment :/

Comment: @GuiFalourd, someone answered yet; [answer link](https://github.community/t/multiline-inputs-for-workflow-dispatch/163906/4)

Comment: @DiegoBandeira, any idea what the answer was? That link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing this answer, there are no updates about this.

There was an answer on [Github communinty](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/12882) and they mentioned that it will be added to their backlog tho.

Until then we found a couple of workarounds, either by passing the changelog as a one-line JSON string and parsing it in our workflow (something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68954061/5078746)), or we create more inputs for our `workflow_dispatch`, I mean something like

```
name: Test
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      entry-header:
        description: 'Version and date'
        required: true
      added:
        description: List of Additions, example: '["Added foo", "Added bar"]'
        required: true
        default: '[]'

      changed:
        description: List of changes, example: '["Changed foo", "Changed bar"]'
        required: true
        default: '[]'
```

Or, if you are using `workflow_call`, you can create a multi-line environment variable and just pass it to your workflow (this one might be unrelated to this example/request)